# Execute php script at particular time (time will be fetched from database)

Tags: php, mysql

I have database structure like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addreminde` (
  `SMSId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SendFrom` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `SendTo` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `Message` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `ReminderTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SMSId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

So i am storing the ReminderTime in database.

Now want to know how i can send a email or (let say execute a php script ) to "SendTo" at the "ReminderTime"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i already..but think if every second i need to send a email then my server will get busy..except cron any other solution...

Comment: then you have to use ajax and setinterval() to check the time stored in database

Comment: You can programmatically create cron jobs at the right time, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5135390/1130734

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in PHP. PHP only comes to 'live' when a user makes a request to the webserver.

As mentioned, a cron job is the way to go. And a query ones a minute and sending some email will not be a big load for your server.

Comment: ok means i can fetch in 10min how many email need to send and then after 10min i will run another cron job. and if any request come in between i will directly give that to process..