# Updating price list dynamically from a webstore to my blog

Tags: php, javascript, ruby, actionscript

I'm trying to implement a website, which provides details on various gadgets and their latest price.

The problem is that price keeps changing everyday and I have to update it manually.

Is there any way I can do it using any client side scripting? Can this be implemented in JavaScript?.

[Here](http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/samsung-galaxy-note-2-msp1846) is an example

They have included the price list of the product in all the online stores. I want this price to get updated as soon as there is any change in Retailers price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sources do not offer an API or RSS feed of any kind to allow you to get he price then you need to scrape the pages you are using to gather your data. Probably best you forget about Javascript for the brunt of this work, the task is quite easy in PHP luckily and you can just set your script to run automatically via CRON every day or every hour or whatever you feel appropriate.

Here is quite a [simple PHP scraper tutorial](http://www.devblog.co/php-web-page-scraping-tutorial/) to get you started.

Or slightly more complex, you can use cURL to do the same job, there is a [cURL Scraper tutorial here](http://spyderwebtech.wordpress.com/2008/08/08/scraping-web-pages-with-curl-tutorial-part-1/).

And finally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script) is a answer from SO on how to run PHP scripts with CRON.