# Automatically url query in every day by Server on Php?

Tags: php, url

I want to ask whether it is possible to send a url query automatically in every day by Server on php?

For example: Goto automatically everyday

"http://www.--------.com/????"

without any one clicking it, just by server or something.

Comment: use cron job for that

Answer (score 2):

Use `cron jobs`  or `schedule tasks`

Ref: http://livecronjobs.com/how-to-set-cronjobs-using-php 
     [How can I set cron job through PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

[cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for *nix servers

[windows task scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) for windows