# executing a cron command to run php script using php

Tags: php, cron

I have spend hours to search about cron execution using php but nothing works for me...i want to execute my php script after every 30 minute..
this is myscript.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$datetime=date("Y-m-d G.i:s", time());
file_put_contents("aaaaa.txt", "The current time is: $datetime\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

and the script I am using to execute cron command...is crontest.php

```
</php
$abc=array();
$dir=dirname(__FILE__);
echo exec("'*/30 * * * * /bin/usr/php $dir/myscript.php' 2>&1", &$abc); 
echo $output;
?>
```

I have tried many different command...
like..

```
"'crontab -l */30 * * * * /bin/usr/php $dir/myscript.php' 2>&1"
"'crontab -l */30 * * * * php myscript.php' 2>&1"
```

but nothing goes in my way..I cant understand what else I can do..
Please someone help, please 
On executing crontest.php I am getting error "sh:*/30 * * * * /bin/usr/php /home/content/71/9988871/html/examples/myscript.php: No such file or directory"

Comment: On running crontest.php I am getting this error..
"sh: crontab -l */5 * * * * /bin/usr/php /home/content/71/9988871/html/examples/myscript.php: No such file or directory"

Comment: It is not `php` executing a crontab sentence. Instead, it is crontab that gets scheduled (with `crontab -e` you edit it) and then it executes it through its daemon.

Comment: Also, edit your answer with the error message you are getting. Do not post it as comment as it is less readable.

Comment: first of all I need to remove the error "sh:...No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cron job in terminal by following the steps:

1) Open terminal

2) Run command

```
crontab -e
```

3) At end add the following

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path of cron file
```

This will automatically run the cron file every 30 minutes.

Comment: I do not have access to terminal..and after all I have to do this with php because I am working on a automated application

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script/5135390#5135390