# schedule a cron job with no traffic and no server access

Tags: php, cron

I would like to know if its possible to write a code in php similar to a cron script to run at a particular time when there is no traffic on site, that means i want the code to run without loading the site. Also I do not want to create a cron job on the server.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But: __why?__

Comment: yes you can but explain what you want actully.

Comment: @AlmaDo how is it possible.

Comment: @rohitarora - a cron to run at certain time, without the site being accessed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set cron job through PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if server is  no too busy, run a cron job:

There's a function for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php

example usage:

```
<?php
$maxLoad = 10; //set some number of max  of processes in the system 
$load = sys_getloadavg();
if ($maxLoad < $load[0]) {
    //run a cron job
}
```

Comment: without loading a site means by not accessing it, by not running the site in the browser

Comment: You can sys_getloadavg() for you server from another site

Comment: well, i needed something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134952/how-can-i-set-cron-job-through-php-script